# How to make Content components show up below AppBar in MUI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make an app bar using the app bar component from MUI v5 but when another content component is rendered it will clip into the app bar, I fixed this using `theme.mixins.toolbar` in v4 how is it fixed in v5 though?, I have tried passing a `position='sticky'` prop that works but it has an undesirable outcome

Comment: what is your undesirable outcome? can you put your code on codesandbox?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: when the position sticky is applied the nav bar gets margins and a shadowing effect on all sides and rather than being the full width of the screen @NearHuscarl , i tried using theme.mixins.toolbar for a styled div component but ended up getting a type error with that approach "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toolbar')",any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sticky `AppBar` combined with `CssBaseline` to solve the issue. The margin around the `AppBar` is set by the user agent stylesheet, `CssBaseline` resets the margin back to 0 to make sure the default styles is sensible:

```
<CssBaseline />
<AppBar position="sticky">
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]